# How to customize shared content on slack, facebook etc?

Tags: facebook, slack, slack-api

I have a website and I want to users to be able to share some content from my website to other apps such as `facebook`, `slack`, etc. The share is a link points to an image in my website. How can I customize the shared content shown no the apps? For example, I'd like to show an image with a text as its title on `slack` rather than a weird long link URL?

Comment: You're going to want to look at "Open Graph" tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments this works by including special meta tags in the header of your HTML page. It is called [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) and both Slack and Facebook support it.

When you then add your URL it will be unfurled to show the content you specified like a specific title, image, description, etc.

Example from one of my websites:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>                      
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">         
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="EVE Info" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Rosie Dunbar | Character" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Rosie Dunbar | Ishikawa Corporation | -0.3" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Character/2112668467_128.jpg" />
```